# For what values of n a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $n$ be element of natural numbers and $f:R \to R$

$f(x)=x^n$ for $x\ge0 $ and $0$ for $x<0$

a)For what values of $n$, $f'$ is continuous on $0$?

I tried using the definition of continuity in a point, that is
$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=f(0)$,

I get $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ for $x \ge0$ and $0$ for $x<0$

Then by computing the lateral limits of $f'$ they both give me zero, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Can you format this question with LaTeX as it makes the question easier to read.

Comment: I'm sorry, how can i do it? I'm on mobile phone and don't have a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous iff $n\ne 1$ (I assume that $n$ is a non-negative integer so the derivative is $0$ for negative $x$ and $nx^{n-1}$ for positive $x$).

Comment: Thank you, but how can i find that if n is not equal to 1 the function is continuous?

Comment: It is certainly continuous for every positive and every negative $x$. The only question is for $x=0$. But if $n>1$ then the one-sided limits  as $x\to \pm 0$ of $f'(x)$ are both $0$ so $f'$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, i don't understand that why "if n > 1 then the one sided limits are..,"

Comment: The limit on the left is $\lim_{x\to -0} 0=0$. The limit on the right is  $\lim_{x\to 0+}nx^{n-1}=0$ if $n>1$.